# Symfony max length of a text field

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

In Symfony, what is the max length of data that I can store in a "text" field. My field is detailed below. I am storing a massive serialized array of data in the field, I just want to make sure that the array stores properly.

```
/**
 * @var text
 * @ORM\Column(name="myField", type="text", nullable=true)
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $myField;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What does that show up in your schema as? `SHOW CREATE TABLE` provides details. Then see how that fares in the [documentation on blob types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html).

Comment: Symphony's limits would be MySQL's limits: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html  for a "text" field, it's 2^16 bytes.

Comment: It shows this: `myField` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you set as the length of the field.
I believe the default length is `65532` bytes but this depends on the underlaying database implementation.

You can change the max length manually.

```
/**
 * @var text
 * @ORM\Column(name="myField", type="text", nullable=true, length="4294967292")
 * @Common\Versioned
 */
private $myField;
```

You can [check this list of maximum sizes per type](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#mapping-matrix) and their which type this matches to per database server.